# Regd WebService to Salesforce

Tags: apex-webservice

We're developing web-service class for inbound integration .

Just curious to know, What we've to provide, besides  WSDL(generated from web service class and Enterprise WSDL for authentication), to external team, once our development is completed so that we're well prepared beforehand.

As we've less idea about inherent structure of WSDL, do we need to provide XSD ,as that is what is written in our requirement doc but that is something we're not clear about. How we can provide XSD ? Is that available Inline in WSDL?

How to provide sample request ?
Currently I'm using DOTNET environment to test the webservice class of Salesforce. And I'm not sure, how I can provide sample request.

Comment: If you are providing inbound service then you can use REST services as compared to SOAP. It would be easy to test. If your has no objection then I uld suggest explore REST option.

Answer (score 1):

The WSDL generated from an Apex class includes the XSD so you don't need to provide that separately. I suggest you give them the Partner WSDL for the authentication part as that is much smaller (as it doesn't have copies of all the standard and custom objects in it).

The client-code to invoke your web service will just about always be generated via tooling so providing the underlying XML messages isn't usually necessary. If you know what the client-side will normally be implemented in (e.g. C# or Java) than providing sample code in that language that makes a request would be the way to go.

In recent years REST/JSON services and authentication via OAUTH have become more popular than WSDL because complicated code generation tools are not needed for these. So as Kiran suggests you should consider using these technologies for your web service instead of WSDL.

Comment: Thanks Keith. These points are really helpful for my understanding